# Display entries which share tags (2 or more)

Tags: relations, tags

I need to be able to display entries (within one section) that share keywords. I don't care what the keywords are, just want to display the entries based on 2 or more shared keywords.

Anyone know how to go about this?

Comment: Are you adding tags (as per your title) to the entry or you want to compare two block of text for words in common?

Comment: Tags will be added to the entries and it's those that we need to use to link the entries together.

Comment: Any ideas @Oli?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After chatting on Discord a bit more, here's a solution in case it helps somebody:

```twig
{# Base query #}
{% set baseQuery = craft
    .entries
    .section('stories')
    .orderBy('RAND()')
    .with(['storyKeywords']) %}

{# Fetch one story at random #}
{% set baseStory = baseQuery.one() %}

Base random story: {{ baseStory.title }}<br>

{# Fetch a second story related to `baseStory` at random #}
{% set relatedStory = clone(baseQuery)
    .relatedTo({
        targetElement: baseStory.storyKeywords,
        field: 'storyKeywords'
    })
    .id('not ' ~ baseStory.id)
    .one() %}

Related Story: {{ relatedStory.title }}<br>

{% set baseKeywords = baseStory.storyKeywords %}
{% set relatedKeywords = relatedStory.storyKeywords %}

<hr>
All tags in common: {{ baseKeywords | filter((tag) => tag.title in relatedKeywords) | join(', ') }} <br>
Number of tags in common: {{ baseKeywords | filter((tag) => tag.title in relatedKeywords) | length }}
```

Comment: This is working like a dream! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following:

```
{# Fetch tags from your current entry's tag field #}
{% set tags = entry.tagFieldHandle.ids() %}

{# Query entries related to your tags #}
{% set entries = craft.entries.relatedTo(tags).all() %}
```

Comment: Thanks but still a little confused. What IDs would I be putting here? I don't want to specify any specific tags or entries, I just need to get back 2 random entries which share at least 2 tags (ideally).

Does that make sense?